# RoR: View Path in Public Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-path

In our application we are storing some views (.erb files) in public/custom_themes/{user}/ folders. We have tried to add the path RAILS_ROOT to `view_paths` and specifying the `/custom_themes/{user}/theme.erb` in `render :layout`. In `development` environment it works fine, but in `production` it takes ages to find the views. It did find but takes around 2-4 minutes to find and render.

Please advise.

Thanks,

Imran

Comment: Your views_paths in production is really enormous ? I think it's your problem :( Too much paths

Comment: @shingara, here is what we have in our view_paths: self.view_paths = ["app/views/", "#{RAILS_ROOT}"]

Comment: Someone might ask "Why I am storing the layouts in public folder?". Anwser: I wanna store all the theme related stuff (layout file, css, images etc) in user folder at a single place.

Comment: the view search parse all file. So if you add RAILS_ROOT, it's enormous. There are a lot of file. It's mandatory to have this issue :( limit your app_view in minimum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use RAILS_ROOT - you don't need the entire rails application (including all vendored/cached gems and plugins!) to be searched.  You only need to add your custom_themes directory:

```
self.view_paths = ['app/views/', "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/custom_themes/"]
```

This should speed it considerably.